# WPF - bind listbox to a ObservableCollection of Images

Tags: wpf, image, listbox, binding, observablecollection

This should be extremely simple, but I jut can't get it to work...

CustomItem is a class that has a property called ThumbnailImage
I am trying to bind an ObservableCollection to a ListBox to display images. This is my code:

```
public ObservableCollection<CustomItem> AvailableItems { get; set; }

 <ListBox Width="103" Height="480" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
             <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=ThumbnailImage}" 
                                             Width="100" Height="100" />
          </Border>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The CustomItem looks like this

```
    public class CustomItem
        public Image ThumbnailImage { get; set; }
    }
```

Nothing is showing up in the ListBox when I run it. Any idea what's going wrong? Thanks!

**-- Edit 1 --** I guess what I can tell from debugging is that closet.Items.Count == 0 when AvailableItems.Count == 5. I tried adding ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" but that didn't help :(

**-- Edit 2 --**

I was doing the following in my XAML

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

instead when I did the following in the codebehind, everything worked:

```
DataContext = this;
```

Comment: I had a similar problem as you. Although my binding worked, the ContentControl showed a string representing the Image Type instead of showing the image. I found out that replacing <ContentControl Content="{Binding ThumbnailImage}"/> by <Image Source="{Binding ThumbnailImage}"/> did the trick. If anyone stumbles on this, that might help them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted seems fine so the problem must be something else

- Does the `ListBox` have the correct DataContext so it can properly bind to `AvailableItems`?
- How are you initializing your `Image` in code?

Example

```
BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage();
source.BeginInit();
source.UriSource = new Uri(yourUriString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
source.EndInit();

ThumbnailImage = new Image();
ThumbnailImage.Source = source;
```

I pasted your code into a sample project and it worked fine, uploaded it here
 http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?m99kv1uglrr31j9

Compare it to your version to see what you're missing

Comment: Thank you so much for the upload, it's a huge help. I am still trying to figure out what my problem is, but so far I noticed that I am doing: DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" instead of DataContext = this; and that's not working the same way. Strange...

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess you either:
1)Didn't initialize your ObservableCollection
2)Didn't set the DataContext of your Window, or
3)You're setting your Images after adding your CustomItem to the ObservableCollection and you haven't implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on your CustomItem class.

Your code plus this seems to work for me:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AvailableItems = new ObservableCollection<CustomItem>();
        Image i = new Image();
        BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
        src.BeginInit();
        src.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg");
        src.EndInit();
        i.Source = src;
        i.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.Fill;

        CustomItem ci = new CustomItem();
        ci.ThumbnailImage = i;

        this.AvailableItems.Add(ci);
    }


    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, I am still going through my code to see what's different

Comment: @Greg R, are you doing the three things I list at the top correctly? Also, you aren't re-setting your AvailableItems collection after you've set the DataContext (in which case your listbox would not be bound to your current 'AvailableItems' collection, but the one that was set when binding first occurred.)?

Comment: For some reason it was a DataContext issue (see Edit #2 in my original question). Even though I have a solution, I don't really understand why the two statements are not equivalent.

Comment: @Greg R, I haven't tried the xaml binding you've used... assuming it is valid... make sure you Initialize 'AvailableItems' before InitializeComponent() is called in your constructor. Then maybe it would work... but I'm not sure though. I always set my data context after the window has been constructed using the Window.Loaded() event.